# ![CDATA[Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element

Tags: web-services, soap, jaxb, cxf, unmarshalling

Below is the XML Input

```
 <_ems:reportEqRepair xmlns:ems="http://ems.services.ws.test.com"
                      xmlns:mod="http://model.ws.test.com">
     <_ems:context>
        <_mod:company>Test</mod:company>
        <_mod:userID>Test_WS</mod:userID>
        <_mod:traceID/>
        <_mod:userLocale>en_US</mod:userLocale>
        <_mod:environment>dev</mod:environment>
        <_mod:submitType>submit</mod:submitType>
     <_/ems:context>
     <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
     <_ems:eqRepairs>XXX</ems:eqRepairs>
<_/ems:reportEqRepair>
```

While sending the above input to SOAPUI, below is the error response i get.

```
![CDATA[Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element
(uri:"http_://ems.services.ws.test.com", local:"context").
Expected elements are <{http_://model.ws.test.com}company>,
```

Please help !! We are using CXF Spring Framework.  Thanks.

JaxB object is as below,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "reportEqRepair", propOrder = {
"context",
"eqRepairs"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "reportEqRepair",
               namespace = "http_://ems.services.ws.test.com")
public class ReportEqRepair {
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ems.services.ws.test.com",
                required = true, nillable = true)
    protected ServiceContext context;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ems.services.ws.test.com",
                required = true)
    protected List<EqRepairInfo> eqRepairs;
```

Comment: These underscores (`'_'`) in "http_:..." in a couple of places don't look right to me.

Comment: I wasn't able to publish the question with too many links, so had to make them as string..

Comment: The XML can't contain QNames `_ems:context` with the namespace definition being given for `xmlns:ems`. `<_/ems:context>` isn't valid XML. The error message isn't consistent with the XML data and class `ReportEqRepair`; it might have come from another unmarshalling run, with a different top level element or another XML (more likely).